# How to avoid grouping images (bars) while selecting contours in an image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I am extracting the length of individual bars from a chart image. It works fine in most of the cases but in some cases the contour groups 2 bars as 1 which is detrimental to my cause. I tried different combinations of canny,dilate, erode, and color scheme. It improved the result only slightly. How can avoid the grouping? Here is the complete code and one image. You can run using this image too see the problem. [image]

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)

image = cv2.imread("somefile.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

#edged=cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_8U, gray, ksize=7)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 50)
cv2.imwrite("test00.png", edged)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
cv2.imwrite("test01.png", edged)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)
cv2.imwrite("test02.png", edged)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)


pixelsPerMetric = 100

for c in cnts:
    orig = image.copy()
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
    print(box)

    box = perspective.order_points(box)
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    for (x, y) in box:
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
    (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
    (blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)

    (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
    (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)

    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)

    cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),
             (255, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),
             (255, 0, 255), 2)

    dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
    dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))


    dimA = dA / pixelsPerMetric
    dimB = dB / pixelsPerMetric

    cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimA),
                (int(tltrX - 15), int(tltrY - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimB),
                (int(trbrX + 10), int(trbrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Image", orig)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image is trivial to segment. The color of the bars is exactly `RGB=(245,222,179)`. You can use OpenCV's function `inRange` to find pixels of this color. In this function, we need to give the color in BGR order, because that is how OpenCV reads in images by default. Here I'm picking a slightly larger range in case the image used JPEG compression (which is lossy and therefore changes pixel values slightly):

```
image = cv2.imread("somefile.png")
mask = cv2.inRange(image, (177, 220, 243), (181, 224, 247))
```

This image `mask` now has perfectly separated bars:

[image: bars]

Comment: Tried it. Doesn' t work. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: It works if I use a custom edge detection function on the image directly without using dilate and erode. But it results in a lot of extra segments which should have been clubbed together.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal: It works for me. I did need to reverse the RGB triplets as I suspected, but after that the code worked fine. Note that you should load the image in color and not convert to gray-value.

Comment: The mask thing works now. How did you get the exact pixel color? For the blue part, I got R: 93 G: 188 B: 210 from a color picker site. I am creating a new mask for the blue color and adding both the masks to get the final mask. But if I specify the range by using subtracting and adding 2 pixels to the values, the blue mask is not generated.

Comment: mask_orange = cv2.inRange(image, (177, 220, 243), (181, 224, 247))
mask_blue = cv2.inRange(image, (208,186,91), (212,190,95))
final_mask = mask_orange + mask_blue. Doesn't give the desired results.

Comment: @Amit: I don't see blue in the image you posted, are you talking about a different image here? Also, don't use a color picker site. Display the image using `cv2.imshow`, then put your mouse cursor over the region of interest, you'll see RGB values on the bottom bar.

Comment: added the image containing the blue color,

Comment: @Amit: I see RGB=(70,130,180), so you could do `mask_blue = cv2.inRange(image, (178,128,68), (182,132,72))`.

Comment: Works. One more query. If i change the dtype to float, I should expect to see more floating numbers in the contour coordinates. But, most of the co-ordinates are still integers. It works for most of the cases but introduces a very slight error in some cases. I would like to eliminate that error.

Comment: @Amit: I'm not sure what you mean. A float image still has bars that occupy individual pixels, their boundaries are still integer locations. Maybe you can post that as a new question, with a [mre]. That should make it easier for you to explain what the issue is.

Comment: I mean I am storing the co-ordinates of the contour boundary in order to calculate the length of the bar. The x, y co-ordinates should have floating values and not integer values. I will post a minimal reproducible example if this is not clear.

Comment: I mean if you hover over the plot, you can see x,y co-ordinates as floating point numbers at the bottom. btw, thanks a lot for your inputs. you have been quite helpful.

Comment: @Amit: The value plotted might have been a floating-point number, but the bar is an integer number of pixels in length. You need to scale this number of pixels with the units/pixel that you determine from the y-axis. That will likely lead to a floating-point value. But it is not as precise as the original value, since that value was rounded to an integer number of pixels.